# What is the meaning of a shell of its former self?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of **a shell of its former self** ? Refer to the article https://www.infoworld.com/article/3632142/how-docker-broke-in-half.html, to quote

> The game changing container company is a shell of its former self.
> What happened to one of the hottest enterprise technology businesses
> of the cloud era?

The reason I ask here instead of looking it up in a dictionary is because

1. The dictionaries I use don't have it, e.g.  longman does not have this expression  https://www.ldoceonline.com/spellcheck/english/?q=a+shell+of+its+former+self
   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-shadow-of-your-former-self?q=a+shadow+of++its++former+self only has "a shadow of your former self"
2. I googled "a shell of its former self" but I can only find some useful information. I had thought if it is a common expression I should be able to get many google search results. The result I thought make sense is [this one](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-shell-of-its-former-self.2201184/) "It means that although the team still exists, it no longer has the talent, spirit, and community support that it once had." But I am not sure if that is an "authority" explanation.
3. So I was wondering is this a common expression that people will understand ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try your searches for "shell of *his* former self" (or *her, your,* or *my)?*

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shell) has **Shell 3.2** An outer form without substance. *He was a shell of the man he had been previously*.

Comment: Oh I didn't but even I tried it now I got result like https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/a+shell+of+his+former+self , which is not good at all.

Comment: See also this NGram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shell+of+%2A+former+self&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cshell%20of%20%2A%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshell%20of%20its%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshell%20of%20his%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshell%20of%20her%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshell%20of%20my%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshell%20of%20your%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshell%20of%20their%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshell%20of%20our%20former%20self%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Hi I updated my question about the google result I feel makes sense ""It means that although the team still exists, it no longer has the talent, spirit, and community support that it once had.""

Comment: Maybe what you need to grasp is the meaning of shell in, e.g., shellfish.

Comment: The "game changing" in your quote, has nothing to do with sports. The first linked story tells you what actually happened to the company, to give the meaning in context. See [game](https://www.lexico.com/definition/game) **3** *informal* A type of activity or business regarded as a game.

Comment: @Xanne I am not sure if you were making a joke or you were serious :$ As you can see English is not my native language. Sorry

Comment: @WeatherVane I know what game changing is . After reading the article I can also guess the meaning "a shell of its former self" So I think the words "It means that although the team still exists, it no longer has the talent, spirit, and community support that it once had."  makes sense. But it seems an odd expression (to me).

Comment: It's not that easy to find; idiom dictionaries don't seem to have "a shell of ... former self" ... perhaps because, as @Weather Vane points out, there are common variations. But it's a common usage. A skeletal staff is a mere vestige of the normal, but 'shell' works better when outwardly there's not a great change, though that's just about all that's left.

Comment: I was not making a joke. Think of a shrimp: it has a shell and the living parts within the shell. The shell can remain when the living parts are gone. Many shells collected on beaches have no living entity in them. The analogy or metaphor is made to an organization (a team, a company, a country) where the external form (the shell) exists, but the vital parts that made it what it was are gone or weakened.

Comment: It's a figure of speech to mean that the core and essence of the object is gone, leaving only the outer shell (or layer) that merely looks like the object. Nothing remains other than its shape or image.

Comment: There are an awful lot of written instances of [*{He was a} mere **husk/shadow** of his former {self}*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mere+husk+of+his+former%22), which is effectively exactly the same relatively transparent imagery, but probably has no "etymological" connection to the ***shell*** version being queried here. So if we define an "idiom" as a usage where the (conventionally established) meaning has to be ***learned*** (isn't obvious from the literal wording), I don't think this qualifies. It's just a "trivial metaphor", not an "idiomatic usage" as such.

Answer (score 1):

"*Shell of its former self*" is the same as "*Shadow of its former self*". It is generally understood and used. You can also say "*Ghost of its former self*"

They all mean that something has greatly diminished compared to a former state. [An example from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shell) explicitly gives:

> 22: An emaciated person.
>
> He's lost so much weight from illness; he's a shell of his former self.

cf. [the definition from Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-shadow-of-your-former-self):

> someone or something that is not as strong, powerful, or useful as it once was:
>
> Since her accident, she’s become a shadow of her former self.

The meaning of the sentence is then that the company in question is smaller, weaker or less important than it used to be.

Comment: There *is* a difference: the 'shell' can seem to be the same until looked at closely, but the 'shadow' is a more obvious change.

Comment: Dubious Can you give an actual explanation instead of what to you are synonymous metaphors?

Comment: One of the comments gives a relevant definition of shell "An outer form without substance" (see Lexico or Merriam-Webster). It implies a similar appearance. If someone is wasted away and deformed he might be "a shadow of his former self" but wouldn't be "a shell of his former self".

Comment: Edited for clarity and linked sources. From the question it seemed that the meaning of "*Shadow...*" was known.